# How to get the top 3 highest result JSON

Tags: json

I have this JSON result:

`[{"columnHeader":{"dimensions":["ga:city"],"metricHeader":{"metricHeaderEntries":[{"name":"ga:users","type":"INTEGER"}]}},"data":{"rows":[{"dimensions":["(not set)"],"metrics":[{"values":["537"]}]},{"dimensions":["Sao Paulo"],"metrics":[{"values":["338"]}]},{"dimensions":["Belo Horizonte"],"metrics":[{"values":["163"]}]},{"dimensions":["Rio de Janeiro"],"metrics":[{"values":["133"]}]},{"dimensions":["Brasilia"],"metrics":[{"values":["85"]}]},{"dimensions":["Campinas"],"metrics":[{"values":["67"]}]},"totals":[{"values":["3269"]}],"rowCount":436,"minimums":[{"values":["1"]}],"maximums":[{"values":["537"]}]}}]`

How can I get the first 3 highest cityes with yours metrics values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far pls?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.